# same uintmax_t representation of long double values

Tags: c, floating-point, hashtable, unions

Why some long double values ​​have the same uintmax_t representation. The problem occurs when using these values ​​as keys in a hash table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

union U{
    uintmax_t u;
    long double d;
};
int main(void)
{
    union U u1, u2;
    u1.d = 1.0L;
    u2.d = 2.0L;
    printf("u1.u: %"PRIuMAX"\n", u1.u);
    printf("u2.u: %"PRIuMAX"\n", u2.u);
    
    //output:
    u1.u: 9223372036854775808
    u2.u: 9223372036854775808
}
```

Comment: You need to add the proper `#include` headers to your code to make it complete.

Comment: What are the sizes of `long double` and `uintmax_t` in your system?

Comment: long double 16, uintmax_t 8

Comment: How is this a problem?

Comment: That's the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/MhqPqqbKx

Comment: Possibly more obvious with [differently sized integers](https://godbolt.org/z/hc9Y7vhnE) – the effect is all the same in both cases…

Comment: @Bob__ Doesn't explain why there is a problem. Or what the problem is.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The OP confirmed that the two members of the union have different sizes in their system, my snippet just tried to visualize what is going on. For a detailed explanation, please read the posted answer.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes they have 2 different sizes. Your snipped only shows that. But that isn't a problem (i don't understand it, everything i see is as expected. Including the output of the OPs program and you linked program, well at least it is one of the expected possibilities. What do i miss?)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 It seems that you are missing the fact `u1.u == u2.u` while `u1.d != u2.d`, which is kinda bad if, like the OP, you wanted to use the integral vaues as keys. My snippet shows (well, I tried) that the `u` member only covers the lower bits (`long double` is a wider type than `uintmax_t`), while to distinguish between the two values you need the higher ones too.

Comment: @Bob__ Of course, `u1.u == u2.u` doesn't (necessarily) imply that `u1.d == u2.d`. But why would you want that? Is that what the OP expected it to be? If so, it is more like a X-Y problem. (accessing with a `uintmax_t`, that may contains padding bits, after writing a `long double` value is UB anyway).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I don't think it's an X-Y problem. `union U { uint64_t u; double d;};` or `union U { __uint128_t u; long double d;};` would have probably "worked" for the OP. The first sentence of the question has been perfectly addressed in John's answer.

Comment: @kaan Aside: Simplify: `printf("u1.u: %"PRIuMAX"\n", u1.u);` --> `printf("u1.u: %ju\n", u1.u);`

Answer (score 4):

There is no "`uintmax_t` representation" of objects of other, incompatible types such as `long double`.  What you are observing is that the first `sizeof(uintmax_t)` bytes of your C implementation's representation of the `long double` value `1.0L` are the same as the same number of bytes of the representation of `2.0L`.  Since the `long double` values are distinct, it follows that the difference between them must occur outside the first `sizeof(uintmax_t)` bytes.

That would not be too surprising because there is no requirement that `uintmax_t` be as wide as `long double`, and because the difference between those particular values will be at the least-significant bit of the exponent field.  That might plausibly be the very last non-padding bit.  `long double` may have 80 or more non-padding bits, whereas `uintmax_t` is frequently only 64 bits wide.

In particular, the output you see is the decimal representation of 2<sup>63</sup>, which is precisely what I would expect in the example cases for

- 64-bit `uintmax_t`, and
- an IEEE-style floating point representation that either

  - starts with a 64-bit mantissa field, or
  - starts with a wider mantissa field and is arranged in little-endian order,
- supposing that the byte order of the mantissa is the same as the byte order of a `uintmax_t`.

Those are eminently plausible conditions, producing the effect that the exponent fields of the `long double`s make no contribution to the observed output.

More generally, since your `long double` is wider than your `uintmax_t`, as you expressed in comments, there is every reason to expect that there will be *many* pairs of distinct `long double`s that match to the first `sizeof(uintmax_t)` bytes.  There are not enough distinct `uintmax_t` values to assign a different one to each distinct `long double` value (unless your `long double` perversely used all of its extra 8 bytes exclusively as padding, which it evidently does not).

Answer (score 1):

> The problem occurs when using these values ​​as keys in a hash table.

Since OP's `long double` byte size exceeds the `uintmax_t` byte size (and so not all differences in a `long double` are seen in a `uintmax_t`), and apparently the code is designed to work with a `uintmax_t` pre-hash value, consider *merging* the extra data.

Some illustrative code:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Form a union of the various types for the hash table.
typedef union {
  long double ld;
  // Maybe other potential data types?
  int (*f)(); // Function pointer
  void *v;    // Object pointer
  complex double cd;
  int i;
// ...
} data;

// Form a union of the data with an array of uintmax_t.
#define HASH_N ((sizeof(data) + sizeof(uintmax_t) - 1)/sizeof(uintmax_t))
typedef union {
  data d;
  uintmax_t u[HASH_N];
} hash;

uintmax_t prehash_long_double(long double ld) {
  hash h = {.d.ld = ld};
  for (size_t i = 1; i < HASH_N; i++) {
    h.u[0] ^= h.u[i];  // Merge data
  }
  return h.u[0];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea because you will be hashing the padding of `data`, as well as any padding that may exist within types like `long double`.  So you'll very likely have situations where objects that should have the same value end up with different hashes.

Comment: @NateEldredge  Reworked: `hash h = {.d.ld = ld};` will initialize `h` with the `long double` and any `union` padding will be zeroed.  Padding within a `long double` is another issue. I suppose you are concerned about a 10-byte `long double` encoded as a 16-byte one with inconsistent padding.